No splashscreen in Cordova app Android 12
As in title. I tried for different png and xml versions of my logo. I keep getting a white screen.
Additionally, I see the following information in the console: "navigator.splashscreen.show()" is unsupported on Android. But it is said in the Cordova documentation: "Starting in Android 12, Google has implemented a new SplashScreen API to control the app launch animation which runs on a device with Android 12 and higher. For backwards compatibility, Cordova has included the core-splashscreen compatibility library which extends this features back to Android API 21 and higher".
Please help.
My settings below:
Cordova Packages:
cli: 12.0.0
    common: 5.0.0
    create: 5.0.0
    lib: 12.0.1
        common: 5.0.0
        fetch: 4.0.0
        serve: 4.0.1

Project Installed Platforms:
android: 12.0.1

My config.xml:
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="24" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="33" />

<platform name="android">
    
        <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
        <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
        <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
        <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
        <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
        <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
        <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
        <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" value="res/screen/android/splash2732.png" />

